# How to create a fragment that slides in from bottom in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

As described in my question I want to be able to slide up a small fragment when I swipe up. It should basically work like the Navigation Drawer that AndroidStudio provides. The problem is that the Navigation Drawer can slide from left or right in the fragment but not from the bottom.
Since there isn´t something like an "onSwipeUp" event I have no idea how I 
could create a workaround.
So is it possible to swipe up a fragment from bottom and if so how?

Comment: It's called BottomSheet

Answer (score 5):

Change your fragment transaction like below:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This **`slide_in_bottom.xml`** will set the entry animation of your `fragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

And this **`slide_out_top.xml`** will set the exit animation of your `fragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! But with this solution there would still be the problem to detect when the animation should be called.

Comment: Is there any way for slide in and out from left and right ? I couldn't find Android providing default animations for left and right sliding. For example - R.anim.slide_in_bottom and R.anim. slide_in_top are available, but R.anim. slide_in_left and R.anim. slide_in_right are not.

Answer (score 1):

**Output**

[image]

**How to slide in Fragment from bottom**

```
currentFragment = DogDetailFragment.getInstance();//<-Your Fragment
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top, R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom)
            .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, currentFragment, "DOGDETAIL")
            .addToBackStack("DOGDETAIL")
            .commit();
```

**How reverse the animation on back button press?**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

**R.anim.slide_in_bottom**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%">
  </translate>
</set>
```

**R.anim.slide_out_top**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-100%">
  </translate>
</set>
```

**R.anim.slide_in_top**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="-0%">
  </translate>
</set>
```

**R.anim.slide_out_bottom**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%">
  </translate>
</set>
```

### Demo project

[Woof Repository](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Woof)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this library, https://github.com/gokhanakkurt/android-menudrawer. It provides a bottom drawer that shows "onSwipeUp".
I don't know if you plan on using it as a simple bottom drawer or you want to further edit it.